# Convert elements in a dictionary to data frame when elements are themselves dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose that I have a dictionary, whose elements are all dataframes with the same column names, how can I convert these dataframes to one big dataframe? i.e. append one dataframe after another for all dataframes stored in this dictionary.

Of course this can be done via a for loop, but since my dictionary is going to be huge, I was wondering if there exists better/elegant ways?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you have a dictionary of similar DataFrames, such as this:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data={"col1":[1,2,3], "col2":["A","B","C"]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data={"col1":[4,5,6], "col2":["D","E","F"]})

dct = dict({"DataFrame1":df1, "DataFrame2":df2})
```

If so then you just use `pandas.concat` and list comprehension to merge the DataFrames together, like so:

```
pd.concat([dct[k] for k in dct])
```